# Passing DateAdd results to url in a batch script with the desired date format

Tags: batch-file, date-formatting, dateadd

Using [DateAdd](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetiment.php#DateAdd) I'm able to add or subtract the desired number of days however I don't know how to get the result in the desired format (mmddyyyy) and add it to a url for download with wget.

```
@ECHO Off

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('DateAdd -30') do set minusonemonth=%%i
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('DateAdd 90') do set addthreemonths=%%i
echo %minusonemonth%
echo %addthreemonths%
```

or

```
@ECHO Off

call dateadd -30
set minusonemonth=%minusonemonth%
call dateadd 90
set addthreemonths=%addthreemonths%

echo %minusonemonth%
echo %addthreemonths%
```

The returned dates should be set to variables and then added to a url string, similar to below, so I can download the file using wget:

```
url="http://www.example.com/load?pStartDate=${minusonemonth}&pEndDate=${addthreemonths}&pServiceID=12552"
```

How can I do this in Windows? It needs run in a scheduled task.

Comment: Lordy.  Might be easier just to `powershell "(get-date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MMddyyyy')"`.  You can capture that with a `for /F` loop.  See `help for` in a cmd console for details.  Or you can code the whole thing in PowerShell and use the `BitsTransfer` module to replace `wget`.  Example .ps1 script: `$start = (get-date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MMddyyyy'); $end = (get-date).AddMonths(3).ToString('MMddyyyy'); $url = "http://www.example.com/load?pStartDate=$start&pEndDate=$end&pServiceID=12552"; ipmo BitsTransfer; Start-BitsTransfer $url 'path\to\output.html'` or similar.

Comment: Thanks Rojo for your help! Using your suggestion I was able to find a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use Invoke-WebRequest because of the way the web server authenticates users. BitsTransfer and WebClient weren't working but both worked with a simple txt file I put on our own web server.

```
$start = (get-date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MMddyyyy');
$end = (get-date).AddMonths(3).ToString('MMddyyyy');
$url = "https://example.com/schedule/Load?pStartDate=$start&pEndDate=$end&pServiceID=1000";
$path = 'C:\Users\public\Documents\report.csv';

#    use BitsTransfer (fails due to web server behavior)
#ipmo BitsTransfer;
#Start-BitsTransfer $url $path;

#    use WebClient (fails due to web server behavior)
#$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
#$client.DownloadFile($url, $path);

#    use Invoke-WebRequest
Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile $path;
```

Thanks to Rojo for his suggestion to use PowerShell and enough direction to get me started.